# How to get data for Matlab cascade Object Detector?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, object-detection, viola-jones

I want to use the trainCascadeObjectDetector in Matlab. It requires an array with the regions of interest of the images. I found two apps where you can put boxes around the rois and the array gets created automatically:

[Cascade Trainer: Specify Ground Truth, Train a Detector](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39627-cascade-trainer--specify-ground-truth--train-a-detector)

[Training Image Labeler](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/trainingimagelabeler-app.html)

Unfortunately they both require Matlab R2014 and I only got R2013.
Is there an other way to define the rois without manually creating the array?

Regards
Philip

Comment: You can contact the author of the Cascade Trainer through the MATLAB File Exchange. He can send you a version that will work with R2013b.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an other solution so I wrote a custom Matlab script for the job. The [imrect](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) function in Matlab is well suitable for this. After the image is shown, the user can drag a rectangular over the region of interest. The coordinates of the region than get stored in a structure together with the path to the image file. Additionally the parts of the image that do not belong to the roi are stored in the negative sample folder.